# Windows Forms display different values in a UserControl based on click event in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have run into a problem when trying to create a Windows Forms App in Visual Studio.

I have some buttons (e.g. b1, b2..) in a UserControl (e.g. ButtonUserControl), and when clicking on a button, a second UserControl (e.g. ProgramUserControl) with a panel (e.g. PanelData) should be added as a child to ButtonUserControl, made visible, and based on the button clicked, different label (e.g. LabelButtonPressed) values should be displayed in the panel. So, for example, if b1 was clicked, LabelButtonPressed value should be changed to "Button: b1" or something similar.

I've tried two approaches:

- Creating boolean Properties for ProgramUserControl (B1Pressed, B2Pressed etc..), setting them to either true or false in the respective button click event and then in the ProgramUserControlDesigner, changing LabelButtonPressed values based on the booleans. This doesn't work, because to avoid creating a new instance of ProgramUserControl on every button click, I create a ProgramUserControl instance in the ButtonUserControl class, but since the instance is only created once, changing the boolean Property values doesn't make a difference.
- Creating a new instance of ProgramUserControl every time a button is clicked. This works, but as the buttons may be pressed multiple times and a new ProgramUserControl is created every time, the Process Memory skyrockets. I tried to counter this by calling Dispose on the old ProgramUserControl (dispose of every control in ButtonUserControl.Controls) before creating a new one, but this doesn't seem to free any process memory.

What are my options?

Comment: WPF or WinForms?

Comment: WinForms, removed false WPF tag.

Comment: if changing the property value makes no difference your user control has coding errors